# Rewrite URL www.domain.com/ru_en/test/test to www.domain.com/ru/en/test/test

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite an url to an other by replacing the underscore _ with slash / in the case of detecting ru_ru or ru_en or cn_cn or cn_en

I m using nginx and I want to use the rewrite to define the rule or the rewrite

```
www.domain.com/ru_en/test/test to www.domain.com/ru/en/test/test
www.domain.com/ru_ru/test/     to www.domain.com/ru/ru/test/
www.domain.com/cn_en/test/test to www.domain.com/cn/en/test/test
www.domain.com/cn_cn/go        to www.domain.com/cn/cn/go
```

The redirect must be done without changing the URL in the address bar.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try with this?

```
rewrite ^/ru_en/(.*)$ http://$server_name/ru/en/$1 permanent; 
rewrite ^/ru_ru/(.*)$ http://$server_name/ru/ru/$1 permanent; 
rewrite ^/cn_en/(.*)$ http://$server_name/cn/en/$1 permanent; 
rewrite ^/cn_cn/(.*)$ http://$server_name/cn/cn/$1 permanent;
```

EDIT: Adding $server_name instead of URL. This will made it universal.

Comment: it works but I do not need the http://example.com in the start also without changing the url in the adress bar. thks a lot.

Comment: I can't use domain.com because StackOverflow doesn't allow that. If this answer helps you, please mark it as solved (so that anyone else can refer to this if needed).

Comment: it is possible to remove the example.com ? I mean I want to make it generic so it work for all domaines also need to make redirect without changing the url on the address bar

Comment: I made it now universal. It will pickup server name from nginx server configurati

Comment: Thanks @BrunoAFK for the help, last thing, it s possible to do the redirect without changing the url on the address bar?

Comment: Yep it's possible. Just use for proxy_pass http:/$server_name

Comment: Thx @BrunoAFK, I have tryed this but not work for me : location /ru/ru {
        rewrite ^/ru/ru/(.*)$ /ru_ru/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://$server_name;
    } if you have a suggestion please dont hesitate

Comment: Rewrite is most certainly not the way to go here. Regexes should be used instead. Also, $server_name will get you in trouble when you have more than one server names defined for the same config as it will use the first one that it sees. You better use $host.